# Kiel bone traduki ‘a rough diamond’ aŭ ‘a diamond in the rough’

Tags: translation

La angla metaforo ‘a rough diamond’ aŭ ‘a diamond in the rough’ povas uziĝi pri homoj. Jen sube estas la difino el dictionary.com:

> an intrinsically trustworthy or good person with uncouth manners or dress

Kiel oni bone tradukus ĉi tion?

Kompreneble eblas simple diri ion kiel “homo krude bonaga” tamen mi preferus similan Esperantan tradukon pro la naturo de la originala verko.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Konsideru:

- *ĉifona kavaliro* — a knight in rags
- *bojato bonkora* — a kindly barked-at person
- *frugilego fidinda* — a trustworthy rook
- *sincero sen ciro* — sincerity without shoe polish
- *gemulo sen poluro* — a gem without polishing

Eble la lasta plej taŭgus.

Comment: Multan dankon! Kie vi trovis ĉi tiujn metaforojn? Mi havas pli da metaforoj, kiujn mi provas traduki :)

Comment: Mi ĵus elpensis ilin, sed la vortludo de *sen ciro* sendube jam okazis ie.

Answer (score 0):

Bonulo, kiu kondutas malbone.

> From Google:
>
> Diamond in the Rough = a person who is generally of good character but
> lacks manners, education, or style.